# clarification of specifics of P0137

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

In the following code I have been meticulous in the following of the standard's words (plus in the light of the wording of [P0137](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0137r1.html)) on object lifetimes.

Note that all memory allocation is through suitably-aligned storage of type unsigned char, as per P0137.

Note also that `Foo` is a POD, with a trivial constructor.

## Questions:

A. If I have misunderstood the standard, and there is any UB here, please kindly point it out (or alternatively confirm that there is no UB)

B. Are the initialisations at A, B, C, D, E, F *strictly* necessary in light of the fact that the construction is trivial, and performs no actual initialisation. If so, please indicate which part of the standard contradicts or clarifies [object.lifetime] in this regard.

## code:

```
#include <memory>

// a POD with trivial constructor
struct Foo 
{
  int x;
};

struct destroy1
{
  void operator()(Foo* p)
  {
    // RAII to guarantee correct destruction order
    auto memory = std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p));
    p->~Foo(); // A
  }
};
std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy1> create1()
{
  // RAII to guarantee correct exception handling
  auto p = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(sizeof(Foo));
  auto pCandidate = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(p.get());
  new (pCandidate) Foo(); // B
  return std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy1>(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(p.release()), 
                                        destroy1());
}

struct call_free
{
  void operator()(void *p) const { std::free(p); } 
};
using malloc_ptr = std::unique_ptr<unsigned char, call_free>;

struct destroy2
{
  void operator()(Foo *pfoo) const {
    // RAII to guarantee correct destruction order
    auto memory = malloc_ptr(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pfoo));
    pfoo->~Foo(); // C
  }
};

std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy2> create2()
{
    // RAII to guarantee correct exception handling
  auto p = malloc_ptr(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(std::malloc(sizeof(Foo))));
  auto pCandidate = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(p.get());
  new (pCandidate) Foo(); // D
  return std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy2>(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(p.release()), 
                                        destroy2());
}

struct nodelete {
  void operator()(Foo * p) {
    p->~Foo();  // E
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<Foo> provide()
{
  alignas(Foo) static unsigned char  storage[sizeof(Foo)];

  auto make = [] {
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(storage);
    new (p) Foo (); // F
    return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(p, nodelete());
  };

  static std::shared_ptr<Foo> pCandidate = make();

  return pCandidate;
}


int main()
{
  auto foo1 = create1();
  auto foo2 = create2();
  auto foo3 = provide();

  foo1->x = 1;
  foo2->x = 2;
  foo3->x = 3;
}
```

Comment: Calling the destructor is only required if the program depends on side-effects of the destructor (C++14 [basic.life]/4), which is not the case for `Foo`. So you can omit all the destruction code.  Releasing storage ends the lifetime of any objects that are in the storage (with UB only if they have such destructors).

Comment: B, D, and F are required as per [intro.object]/1 list of things that create an object. Technically I think F should be `auto p = new(storage) Foo();` instead of the two lines you have, and similarly for B and D - you're meant to use the return value of placement new. I'm not aware of any requirement that `std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(sizeof(Foo));`'s storage be suitably aligned for `Foo`, so the B case might have an alignment problem.  I don't have time right now to write a rigorous answer but will revisit after the weekend. Good post

Comment: I'd suggest rolling back your last edit as it makes it very difficult to understand what the question is, as it now starts with half-answer half-commentary.

Comment: @Barry so done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### On `create1`

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy1>(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(p.release()), destroy1());
> ```

This doesn't work, because you're using the wrong pointer.

`p.release()` thinks it points to an `unsigned char[]`. However, that's not the object you want to point to. What you want to point to is the object that lives inside this array, the `Foo` you've created.

So you are now subject to [basic.life]/8. The gist of that is that you can only use the previous pointer as a pointer to the new object if they are of the same type. Which they're not in your case.

Now, I could tell you to `launder` the pointer, but the more reasonable way to handle this is to just store the pointer returned by the placement-new call:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(sizeof(Foo));
auto ret = std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy1>(new(p.get()) Foo(), destroy1());
p.release();
return ret;
```

That pointer will always be correct.

Your use of of placement-new is *not optional*. [intro.object]/1 tells us:

> An object is created by a definition (3.1), by a new-expression (5.3.4), when implicitly changing the active member of a union (9.3), or when a temporary object is created (4.4, 12.2).

When you allocate an `unsigned char[]`, that's the object you have created in that storage. You cannot simply pretend that it is a `Foo`, just because `Foo` is an aggregate. [intro.object]/1 doesn't allow that. You must explicitly create that object via one of the mechanisms listed above. Since you can't use a definition, `union` member activation, or temporary objects with arbitrary memory buffers to create objects from existing storage, the only recourse you have to create objects is a new-expression.

Specifically, placement-new.

As for `delete1`, you do need a custom deleter, since the default deleter will call `delete` on the `Foo` pointer. Your code is as follows:

```
auto memory = std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p));
p->~Foo();
```

`unsigned char[]` has some special logic to it, in terms of how it behaves when objects are allocated in their storage, thanks to [intro.object]/3-4. If the object entirely overlays the storage of the `unsigned char[]`, then it functions as if the object were allocated within the array. That means that the `unsigned char[]` is still technically there; it has not destroy the byte array.

As such, you can still delete the byte array, which your code here does.

#### On `create2`

This is also wrong, due to further violations of [basic.life]/8. A fixed version would be similar to the above:

```
auto p = malloc_ptr(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(std::malloc(sizeof(Foo))));
auto ret std::unique_ptr<Foo, destroy2>(new(p.get()) Foo(), destroy2());
p.release();
return ret;
```

Unlike new-expressions, `malloc` never creates an object via [intro.object]/1; it only acquires storage. As such, placement-new is again required.

Similarly, `free` just releases memory; it doesn't deal with objects. So your `delete2` is essentially fine (though the use of `malloc_ptr` there makes it needlessly confusing).

#### On `provide`

This has the same [basic.life]/8 problems that the rest of your examples have:

```
alignas(Foo) static unsigned char storage[sizeof(Foo)];
static auto pCandidate = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new(storage) Foo(), nodelete());
return pCandidate;
```

But other than that, it's fine (so long as you don't break it elsewhere). Why? That's complex.

[basic.start.term]/1 tells us that static objects are destroyed in the reverse order of their initialization. And [stmt.decl]/4 tells us that block-scoped static objects are initialized in the order they are encountered in a function.

Therefore, we know that `pCandidate` will be destroyed *before* `storage`. So long as you don't keep a copy of that `shared_ptr` in a static variable, or otherwise fail to destroy/reset all such shared objects before termination, you should be fine.

---

That all being said, using blocks of `unsigned char` is really pre-C++11. We have [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) and [`std::aligned_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_union) now. Use them.

Comment: Thank you Nichol. I appreciate the comment about aligned storage. I wanted to avoid that because it was tangential to what I wanted to find out. 
Understood re the result of placement new. I am guessing that this is to allow the compiler to put some magic prior to the objects address should it feel the need.
Of the above, the most 'safe' is using the result of malloc (because this is storage and not an object). Question B then remains - do I *really* need to call placement new - since the object is a POD, it's address *must* be the same as the buffer, *and* it does not require initialisation

Comment: @RichardHodges: "*Of the above, the most 'safe' is using the result of malloc (because this is storage and not an object).*" I fail to see why that is particularly "safe", relative to anything else. If you want to just allocate storage, you can call `operator new` directly. As for the question of placement-new, I've updated the answer to address that.

Comment: All of the above I am asking because sometimes c++ shares struct definitions with c (e.g. mysql.h, openssl.h). c can make a struct instance available to c++ (they share exactly the same layout, by definition). but the c struct will not have had a placement new called upon it. By strict reading of the standard this implies that c++ may not treat the instance as an object while c may. This seems at odds with the wording around standard layout and PODs (at least to me).
Again, I am aware of aligned_storage. That is not my concern here.

Comment: ...forgot to say, it's a great answer BTW. Very informative. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHodges: The interoperation between C and C++ is an implementation-defined area. The interface between C and C++ functions exist (in the sense that `extern C` is a thing), but whether what C does with memory is good enough to be an object for C++ purposes is implementation-defined.

Comment: That is a shocking revelation! It is essentially saying that calling out to any c library (other than presumably parts of the c runtime library) is implementation-defined (i.e. unreliable). This surely cannot be the intention of the standards committee? This seems to me to be too important a thing to simply dismiss it as "implementation defined". c-standards-conforming libraries either work with c++ or they do not - otherwise the entire edifice of computing is built on wishes and rainbows, is it not?

Comment: `unsigned char[]` is special. It *provides storage for* an object you placement-`new` in it ([\[intro.object\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#3)), and so that object is *nested within* said `unsigned char[]` ([\[intro.object\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#4)), which means that the placement-`new` doesn't end the lifetime of the `unsigned char[]` ([\[basic.life\]/1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#1.4)) because its storage is being reused by an object nested within it..

Comment: Since there is no lifetime-ending, [basic.life]/8 is not applicable. The problem here is that the result of the `reinterpret_cast` cast doesn't point to the `Foo` object because the objects at issue are not pointer-interconvertible (see [\[expr.static.cast\]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#13)). Instead, "the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion", which means it still points to the first element of the `unsigned char[]` array, even though its type is `Foo *`.

Answer (score 1):

If you take seriously Core Issue 1776 and the never voted for idea that "that malloc alone is not sufficient to create an object", then you have to take seriously these ideas:

- unions were not usable without UB in C++ until quite recently, as the lifetime of their members was not defined
- string literals cannot be examined, as their lifetime is never started

and many other deeper more difficult controversies and contradictions, like what is a lvalue, an object, is lifetime a property of a preexisting object (that exists outside it's life), etc.

Yet I don't see people taking at least the two bullet points seriously. Why would the claim in the DR be taken seriously then?

Comment: :) we should hang out. I annoy people with my difficult questions too.

Answer (score 0):

"Core Issue 1776: Replacement of class objects containing reference members" is based on an obvious and serious interpretation error, and as such should be dismissed. The error is here:

> Drafting note: this maintains the status quo that malloc alone is not
>   sufficient to create an object

This goes against the status quo that "malloc alone" is indeed sufficient to create an object, as malloc returns suitably aligned storage, which is and has always been sufficient to create an object.

A core issue is not the standard. It is an opinion about the standard. That opinion is in error.

Comment: You'll be amazed to learn that the standards committee really does intend that malloc alone is not sufficient to create a POD. Writing to a structure that was created by some other language (e.g. C) is IB or UB depending on whether it's an array or not. For what it's worth, I think they are unhinged, but there you are. Apparently in c++, memory is not really memory.

Comment: @RichardHodges The C++ committee is simply ... gone. You see what I mean.

Comment: @RichardHodges I admit that enough committee members say that so it's the consensus, what I don't accept is that it's the intent status quo. If it had been the intent (and not a stupid mistake like the fact using string literals has UB), it would have been documented a silent change WRT identical C code; and inane code with sequences as `//* <NL> */` was listed a code possibly broken when compiling in as C++! The issue I have is that ppl don't take seriously the fact you can't refer to a base class w/ a ptr but they say you can't write C/C++ code.