# Manipulating byte vector through float pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to manipulate an `std::vector<unsigned char>` through its data pointer as if it were a container of `float`?

Here is an example that compiles and (seemingly?) runs as desired (GCC 4.8, C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(2 * sizeof(float));
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<float *>(bytes.data());
    ptr[0] = 1.1;
    ptr[1] = 1.2;
    std::cout << ptr[0] << ", " << ptr[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet successfully writes/reads data from the byte buffer as if it were an array of `float`. From [reading about reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) I'm afraid that this might be undefined behavior. My confidence in understanding the type aliasing details is too little for me to be sure.

Is the code snippet undefined behavior as outlined above? If so, is there another way to achieve this sort of byte manipulation?

Comment: I'd say it breaks strict aliasing. The best solution is to create a new vector (of `float`) of the correct size, and do a byte-wise copy from the byte vector to the float vector (i.e. `memcpy`).

Comment: @Gupta this is a simplified example of my use case, I'm not sure if me taking the time to explain is worth it. Long story short this has to do with the fact that what is 'float' in this example is in fact a type that is only known during runtime.

Comment: @Groo I am planning to use `bytes` afterwards. More accurately, a library is using its data pointer to read the floats.

Comment: @Groo No it isn't.

Comment: @Gupta No it isn't.

Comment: @Gupta If you could post an answer with a link to the relevant wording of the standard or at [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) that would be great

Comment: @Groo I am casting and passing the pointer on to a library routine accepting `void *`

Comment: @Stargazer Seems like a `reinterpret_cast<void*>(vec.data())` on a `std::vector<float>` would be more appropriate then

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings see my first comment towards Gupta for why things aren't that easy.

Comment: @Stargazer Then you're stuck with antics :) (Please fully explain the use case in the question.)

Comment: @Stargazer: you are allowed to do vice versa (cast the `float*` to `char*` for byte inspection), although the writers of the library will likely rely on UB in that case. So a defined way would be to create an array of floats and then `reinterpret_cast` it before passing to the library.\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Legal answer

No, this is not permitted.

C++ isn't just "a load of bytes" — the compiler (and, more abstractly, the language) have been told that you have a container of `unsigned char`s, not a container of `float`s. No `float`s exist, and you can't pretend that they do.

The rule you're looking for, which is known as *strict aliasing*, may be found under [`[basic.lval]/8`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8).

The opposite would work, because it is permitted (via a special rule in that same paragraph) to examine the bytes of any type via an `unsigned char*`. But in your case, the quickest safe and correct way to "get" a `float` from something that starts life as `unsigned char` is to `std::memcpy` or `std::copy` those bytes into an actual `float` that exists:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(2 * sizeof(float));
float f1, f2;

// Extracting values
std::memcpy(
   reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f1),
   bytes.data(),
   sizeof(float)
);

std::memcpy(
   reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f2),
   bytes.data() + sizeof(float),
   sizeof(float)
);

// Putting them back
f1 = 1.1;
f2 = 1.2;

std::memcpy(
   bytes.data(),
   reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f1),
   sizeof(float)
);

std::memcpy(
   bytes.data() + sizeof(float),
   reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f2),
   sizeof(float)
);
```

This is fine as long as those bytes form a valid representation of `float` on your system. Granted it looks a little unwieldy, but a quick wrapper function will make short work of it.

A common alternative, assuming you only care about `float`s and don't need a resizable buffer, is to produce some [`std::aligned_storage`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50271887/4386278) then do a bunch of *placement new* into the resulting buffer. Since C++17, you could alternatively play around with [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder), though resizing the vector (read: reallocating its buffer) would also be inadvisable in that scenario.

Also, these approaches are quite involved and result in complex code that not all your readers will be able to follow. If you can launder your data such that it "is" a sequence of `float`s, you may as well just make yourself a nice `std::vector<float>` in the first place. Per the above, it is permitted to get and use an `unsigned char*` to that buffer if you wish.

It ought to be noted that there is much code out there in the wild that uses your original approach (particularly in older projects with a barebones C heritage). On many implementations, it may appear to work. But it is a common misconception that it is valid and/or safe, and you're prone to instruction "re-ordering" (or other optimisations) if you rely on it.

---

#### Hedge-betting answer

For what it's worth, if you disable strict aliasing (GCC permits this as an extension, and LLVM doesn't even implement it), then you can probably get away with your original code. [Just be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225741/4386278).

Comment: (I didn't downvote) `std::aligned_storage` isn't necessarily a replacement for vector because the size cannot be dynamic. Granted, the size used in the example is constant.

Comment: Yeah I should probably mention that caveat. I dun an editz

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to manipulate an std::vector through its data pointer as if it were a container of float?

Not quite. Your example has UB indeed.

However, you can reuse the storage of those bytes to create the floats there. Example:

```
float* ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<float*>(bytes.data()));
std::uninitialized_fill_n(ptr, 2, 0.0f);
```

After this, the lifetime of the unsigned char objects has ended, end there are floats there instead. Using `ptr` is well defined.

Whether this would be useful for you is another matter. Start with a simpler design first: Why not simply use `std::vector<float>`?

Comment: How well does this approach interact with `vector`'s destruction (and/or reallocations), if applicable?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Reallocations: I don't know, maybe fine, maybe technically not; I would recommend to not do reallocations. Destruction: Fine because both unsigned char and float are trivial.

Comment: Yep, indeed, agreed.

Comment: @eerorika The snippet in the question is a simplified version of a tougher case I came across in practice. I can solve the problem using other approaches but they are ugly and verbose. Were byte manipulation as I desired legal then it would be the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Stargazer For what it's worth, if you disable strict aliasing (GCC permits this as an extension), then you can probably get away with it. But be careful. (Just realised this and added it to my answer :D)