# Combining __restrict__ and __attribute__((aligned(32)))

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, memory-alignment, restrict-qualifier

I want to ensure that gcc knows:

1. The pointers refer to non-overlapping chunks of memory
2. The pointers have 32 byte alignments

Is the following the correct?

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
void f(const  T* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) x,
       T2* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) out) {}
```

Thanks.

Update:

I try to use one read and lots of write to saturate the cpu ports for writing. I hope that would make the performance gain by aligned moves more significant.

But the assembly still uses unaligned moves instead of aligned moves.

Code (also at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZAagAqATwAOmectHF5aLPISZimUvJLyGqJunmt5mAB5MAtqoaYAdBwAMAQQBuqHg2ggCOIkzGEGgsggTy8gBmlkwEAFTyAPqZxnHEeMgE2VmZqQT5AEYiBJjZUEwMeMAsmOgQAMxcAJQ98g6kPr4JwyMJMXHyeCzxgngAXiaDo8vJVuklueUFRZklZZXVtZn1jc2tHd29ogTeA37Lo6upGdmb%2BYXF2ft4VTV1EA0mi02p0el0zNV6EsHsMnutXpg8ttPqUCFtfkcTkDzqCrtUuHchjCEnCXjlEVsPrsvmiDn9jgDTsCLmCIQR2oTiSSUvDyUiqXtaT9Dv9AWcQZdwdcACzgjgAdj491h5ggU3ieHkHHaABF5N5tTxJlr2gBheSzBaGrW8fh4OWK6HLa4GgCsPDwHFdeu1eocXo9Xp1hqdo2utADnu9Jr9kaD8gy/vdUeD7SVROd%2BLj0d9fWzesT%2BYTeeTQZDysz7KLuaTgejhdL9ZLdYLzZT5YzYeq0ururb8YbLeLtZTw6Lg/badDCuDfhnUi6jGkrqkpBY0m8q9Q0lN/H4Fu0Eht7Voq4IG4Xi4A1iBpe0PAA2LjeV3tV3y9ry58Ph/S6VLqRpVXdcpE3UhtykVdBBAW5z1AhdSDgWAkDQVw8HcMgKGiVA0IwkBgAADgJRJ0JqYhoIgCoL1ICopkiZRpFPUhUOcTBpgAeRYBgGPg0gsGcVhgHcaj8GMQo8H8RFqMcTBkEORjV3VTAGGoxoKmIejTQwSQpCYrZnAUxdmDYFA914RgfmgyBF1QVQCDwVBYmkABaATxAQX0ECYQQAHdlIYeRnPY9ooMPSRaCM5dgOoiCHAIh9nN/eRgGQZB5AIjwuHkCBcEIcxuBPUwtNwoxjwi%2BRd1tXgzwvHpSBvV0Hw8T8AE5pV/Lgn3lFr2jfB8AKAtcYukKCYNIODNzqlSpC4aLeIgmr4LqyTyIc9dpSAA%3D))

```
int square(const  float* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) x,
           const int size,
           float* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) out0,
           float* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) out1,
           float* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) out2,
           float* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) out3,
           float* __restrict__ __attribute__((aligned(32))) out4) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        out0[i] = x[i];
        out1[i] = x[i] * x[i];
        out2[i] = x[i] * x[i] * x[i];
        out3[i] = x[i] * x[i] * x[i] * x[i];
        out4[i] = x[i] * x[i] * x[i] * x[i] * x[i];
    }
}
```

Assembly compiled with gcc 8.2 and "-march=haswell -O3"
It is full of vmovups, which are unaligned moves.

```
.L3:
        vmovups ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rbx+rax]
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm1
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [r14+rax], ymm0
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [r15+rax], ymm0
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [r12+rax], ymm0
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rbp+0+rax], ymm0
        add     rax, 32
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L3
        and     r13d, -8
        vzeroupper
```

Same behavior even for sandybridge:

```
.L3:
        vmovups xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rbx+rax]
        vinsertf128     ymm1, ymm2, XMMWORD PTR [rbx+16+rax], 0x1
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm1
        vmovups XMMWORD PTR [r14+rax], xmm0
        vextractf128    XMMWORD PTR [r14+16+rax], ymm0, 0x1
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovups XMMWORD PTR [r13+0+rax], xmm0
        vextractf128    XMMWORD PTR [r13+16+rax], ymm0, 0x1
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovups XMMWORD PTR [r12+rax], xmm0
        vextractf128    XMMWORD PTR [r12+16+rax], ymm0, 0x1
        vmulps  ymm0, ymm1, ymm0
        vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rbp+0+rax], xmm0
        vextractf128    XMMWORD PTR [rbp+16+rax], ymm0, 0x1
        add     rax, 32
        cmp     rax, rdx
        jne     .L3
        and     r15d, -8
        vzeroupper
```

Using addition instead of multiplication ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZAagAqATwAOmectHF5aLPISZimUvJLyGqJunmt5mAB5MAtqoaYAdBwAMAQQBuqHg2ggCOIkzGEGgsggTy8gBmlkwEAFTyAPqZxnHEeMgE2VmZqQT5AEYiBJjZUEwMeMAsmOgQAMxcAJQ98g6kPr4JwyPDMXHyeCzxgngAXiaDo8tJKeklueUFRZklZZXVtZn1jc2tHd29ogTeA34ro8lW69mb%2BYXF2ft4VTV1EA0mi02p0el0zNV6EsHsMnqkMq9MHltp9SgQtr8jicgedQVdqlw7kMYQk4S8ckith9dl90Qc/scAadgRcwRCCO0iSTSWsERTkdS9nSfod/oCziDLuDrgAWcEcADsfHusPMECm8Tw8g47QAIvJvDqeJNte0AMLyWYLI3a3j8PDypXQ5bXQ0AVh4eA4bv1Ov1Dm9nu9uqNztG11oga9PtN%2BtdUeDtuN8Y90ZD7WVxJdBITMb97MjqcT/HZ7qDPtDKuzHNzvr17K4taTBdrlaz4eqMqb%2Beu7W7vAbrYzYcVIb8o6kXUY0jdUlILGk3jnqGkZv4JeEYgktvatDnBEXk6nAGsQDL2h4AGxcbxu9puhXtBU3y%2BXmUy6dSGVzhdSJekFcpDnQQQFuA8/0nUg4FgJA0FcPB3DICholQeDEJAYAAA5CUSBCamIECIAqQ9SAqKZImUaQ91IODnEwaYAHkWAYSiINILBnFYYB3BI/BjEKPB/CREjHEwZBDioucNUwBgSMaCpiAos0MEkKRqK2ZxJKnZg2BQddeEYH4QMgKdUFUAg8FQWJpAAWk48QED9QRWHQZQFOCYANBshj2mA7QJDobSZx/EjAIcTDLxst95GAZBkHkTCPC4eQIFwQhzG4XdTGUtCjB3WhwTXO1eH3Q8elIU83UvDwnwAThlN8uGvBVavae9L0/b951C6RgNA0hwKXcrZKkLgQrYwDSog8qhIIyyFxlIA%3D)).
Still unaligned moves.

Comment: Yes? Do you have evidence that it isn't correct?

Comment: The program didn't crash when I use an unaligned chunk of memory. But I haven't checked the assembly. I seem to remember reading that gcc sometimes uses unaligned load even when the pointer is aligned. But I am not sure if my memory is correct.

Comment: Why should it? Giving gcc hints to pointers alignements is one thing - expecting it to crash is another. It may crash, it may not, both implementations being valid. What is the assembly of the function generated by the compiler? By inspecting the assembly instructions you can know if unaligned memory access may result in some "crash".

Comment: But what if it doesn't use aligned load cpu instructions? Are you sure it uses them? What is the generated assembly by the compiler? The best would be if you would recreate an MCVE - using ex. http://godbolt.org .

Comment: Checked assembly. Full of unaligned moves even when I try to saturate the write ports of the cpu. I seem to remember unaligned store means cpu need to fetch two instead of 1 cache line. When all write ports are saturated, aligned store should have better throughput.

Comment: Since Nehalem and Bulldozer, there's zero penalty for `movups` load or store with pointers that are actually aligned at runtime.  (And with AVX, you're not losing out on the compiler's ability to fold loads into memory operands.)  But yes, if gcc knows that memory is aligned, it will normally use `[v]movaps`, not `ups`.

Comment: But as you noticed, gcc defaults to enabling `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load` (and store) without `-march=haswell`, in many tuning settings, leading to a possibly-significant penalty even if data does turn out to be aligned at runtime.  [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726)  Plus there's the code bloat from the unaligned startup loop with older gcc.  (But it's always going to emit cleanup code for a non-whole number of full vectors, unless you do `size &= -8ULL` or use a `__builtin_unreachable()`.)

Comment: BTW, you fall off the end of a non-`void` function, so it contains UB that could lead to gcc and/or clang leaving out the `ret` instruction or otherwise being weird.  Don't do that.

Comment: replaced int return type by void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, using `float *__attribute__((aligned(32))) x` means that the pointer itself is *stored* in aligned memory, not pointing to aligned memory.<sup>1</sup>**

There is a way to do this, but it only helps for gcc, not clang or ICC.

See [How to tell GCC that a pointer argument is always double-word-aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608171/how-to-tell-gcc-that-a-pointer-argument-is-always-double-word-aligned/43039936#43039936) for `__builtin_assume_aligned` which works on all GNU C compatible compilers, and [How can I apply __attribute__(( aligned(32))) to an int *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211864/how-can-i-apply-attribute-aligned32-to-an-int) for more details about `__attribute__((aligned(32)))`, which does work for GCC.

**I used `__restrict` instead of `__restrict__`** because that C++ extension name for C99 `restrict` is portable to all the mainstream x86 C++ compilers, including MSVC.

```
typedef float aligned32_float __attribute__((aligned(32)));

void prod(const aligned32_float  * __restrict x,
          const aligned32_float  * __restrict y,
          int size,
          aligned32_float* __restrict out0)
{
    size &= -16ULL;

#if 0   // this works for clang, ICC, and GCC
    x = (const float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(x, 32);  // have to cast the result in C++
    y = (const float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(y, 32);
    out0 = (float*)__builtin_assume_aligned(out0, 32);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        out0[i] = x[i] * y[i];  // auto-vectorized with a memory operand for mulps
      // note clang using two separate movups loads
      // instead of a memory operand for mulps
    }
}
```

([gcc, clang, and ICC output on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByHQGY8VLFQDUAfVcBxAHIBVAMLuWhIAggD0oc50rACezszIBKZsMc54ALYADqx4mEZx2cC0aZj0zjTEzsDI2iHhzrSoBM7IahqRFQCSfn5BwQTRGZhOZayozE1seIVDtryuVKPjbq7jBMR4AEamBJjuUJPT6BCzAJRnWrb6IXaYrEaYvf2DwwtjEwW0M3Ov4xe6zs46gAVADyABEQSBnGlmNENphllgWkZBshnCZigQEHg2uVnABZBgANT8pHa%2BSmtGYRmOvBOvTqTyGmBcBypNNOIzeFMOs3miwIf0BEQag16N1o%2BCo4uuIQAbqg8OhnBliBgIGhaEZ3pSvvzuc4AFTLYi5NZ4BLOAAepF6APtDoBmu1PM%2B6D5PyaRpNZvWluitpCjuDOKaRjwAC9MIHgsHHWy9Z7je5Tdq/U0zAQJCdnFppFdY/bw1Hc7wAGwXMHOAC0nDLPgAMg2/jLgnYHM4JPbGdi8gB3EgAazyeJa6mAZK6pLikucHm6dvtVtztirGroLqTJ3cWzwrAIOJWRiMpmKKw%2BQwgNucpxbQftsUrznXWqaW53pj3B9oR5PZ4TRwBjedJ3oWAKZl2T7UAKhrbq4u77oe1J/rsAEQBBZK3pc4q8LYJRSq2Dp4hAoapCuVYSEKeArn46KRg8lylvoeh4DmeYFnGkTbJRYi6HgWhiFWT5WgJfECVWxrRKJ/GCUKwrOMEPigtWRLYH4oIAEodAAWtgYJkqMqCDnEExGGkZQkM4WJ4EYi4OnUDQ7M0rTAM4pjhm0BADuimAZMwxDjAiaSoHKpgZHkizoLZ972REOLapgzDKqgrLQpgwXELEqCDAFs54mkpisOFdm5tIYLimVrZVbhDiSiyyzIFk7lNdFbY1bQLSmFgNHaugbLcAgFzYDheGSg4jwDMyLimLQeB0KV/xstSEB1jmnplKJIjiUKeZVmyVCmKBDIRNZeToKguS0GAVhNAOxDGXKmCZc4fa3Kwx3OTNg45BUWLqMsCHfr%2Bp6oRe6AfbkqJ4MksR9oQCAKUSAAarYKkqKpqugrhyrwL4uvtpgAsmripualpWqYMacfazo6oUB1Ez6aYWk00SUyVcakcW0Yc8GBPE6T6ZcVmh0xZxbH5iV3OlhWq41nWjbNthYvhLTXJLIaKa%2Biz1rkdapjVkN0qMfJLDajirnMH2sJlGq5lYgiAFWZNzijPceQO66xSlDiNAWRUVRouoypjhoJWqxub4CkaWvM/6ets4btjYMb/zyTCcIIvCLDuQir31Jgj0VPEiQw84WCmlQJSWFZCCOx83sENWpoAI6fqayoZIq9BPdw4ehOtmsk9rloQXrEEG0bR1i8RpHUU%2BlGMfPti0dzO16AYrELbz4HcYdvEyWC3DSrxPFCXLFPSeJx%2BiWf3ps1fgk36f23K2BjoT4/R8n7onDiXrl8D7Xx/n/QS9995iSfiA1%2BHE4yfyAVA0SvB/7CQgYfZ%2BuhkFgMkmg4BSCYE72FhIXBiDeK2BQRfEh39RLkOwc4B%2BCDqFkIIWLWKEEv4AI4ZJL%2BoEHS7QquVEIVgTiqBAFYMQVhSC0DERISRqAxE9A3nodEZgLAIjsJwSRBAZHCJEYOEAvBBDcE4PwfgvARDmM4JwQQuFpBiFEVYEQki0hcAkBIKROjSDyKsJIowIB3HaKsLIkRcBYBIDQJkPcT1yCUAiRkKJxAQDADMaQKgX4np%2BIgBsTxGwcT%2BWiGIzRpAImNxBLQGInisAwg0OwSpeBTQJDwI9PxQTJGYCtJgZA2xrBFNDLcTx2QNgBUyn4DAPStHrBcVYTRIiaD0CYGwDgPABDCHEFIWQ8gFAuRQAYAwqhNh%2BMgCI7KB4NxiJrDCCwg1VwIGpK9VgrALnMDlMuasIJbA1ioFQakTcYRYk%2BQ0asqA0iEGrFQAKxRqxdz6RUasaRAXPKtL41RlguAiNYGIiRHjWleLEVafgZZqxlhEJUaozh%2BB8GfLgQglkNFklGZE9gFQNE5kUcxXQWidFnFIHXJKT1KB6IMbYYxZZrFiF4BIMs0hbASFENIBxTjsWyNxT44w/jSCBOCaQUJiAUDAviUymJ65GX8tDsAaQbjUnpOIJk7JOLclUkyoUyRJSSgEDKRUnFVTxy1K9fUzpB5mmePaZ07pzryA9wxTiwZwzoijKwOG80UyZmpLoIwFgtTllCFEJIGQmytnjh2UowwgzDkQGORkU5WoxFvI%2BWC752o4XjARtWXqlZCiHWLZwaQNYADqyQ%2B3tLWMwAEcKEUvOReYVFnB0WYskdInF3j8WEuJc5cczhpDcAkFuql%2BAiDMtwpwel%2BqEmlk5GygwnLWncv0bhbgZiRCCAkLwaQZYJC2H4LYD99io2KoXcq7xvj1WauEdqmAuq4kJKNZBplIALTIGsUetJ%2B4MmUDtcqh1%2BTw2uvoB6gpXr0o%2BusMq/ADTA25GDR0rpOxw19KjcqmN%2BT43jI1ZM51sy00LMzXwbNay835tUIW7Qxb9kbDLRWqtLTa2TrUWihxWL/1yLxQSolJL4POGsVu4xu6aUHtsEe5wDKDVPTPbYVluy9BXuCYKu9D6n0vrfR%2Br9/Af1iL/Z4wDaqAlctnVYXgzjXHuMUyqqzujSBF3DHQEAIggA%3D)).

---

GCC and clang will use `movaps` / `vmovaps` instead of `ups` any time it has a compile-time alignment guarantee.  (Unlike MSVC and ICC which never use `movaps` for loads/stores, a missed optimization for anything that runs on Core2 / K10 or older).  And as you noticed, it's applying the `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load`/`store` effects for tunings other than Haswell ([Why doesn't gcc resolve _mm256_loadu_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726))., another clue that your syntax didn't work.

`vmovups` is not a performance problem when used on aligned memory; it performs identically to `vmovaps` on all AVX-supporting CPUs when the address is aligned at runtime.  So in practice there's no real problem with your `-march=haswell` output.  Only older CPUs, before Nehalem and Bulldozer, always decoded `movups` to multiple uops.

The real benefit (these days) to telling the compiler about alignment guarantees is that compilers sometimes emit extra code for startup/cleanup loops to reach an alignment boundary.  Or without AVX, compilers can't fold a load into a memory operand for `mulps` unless it's aligned.

**A good test case for this is `out0[i] = x[i] * y[i]`, where the load result is only needed once.**  Or `out0[i] *= x[i]`.  Knowing alignment enables `movaps`/`mulps xmm0, [rsi]`, otherwise it's 2x `movups` + `mulps`.  You can check for this optimization even on compilers like ICC or MSVC, which use `movups` even when they *do* know they have an alignment guarantee, but they will still make alignment-required code when they can fold a load into an ALU operation.

**It seems `__builtin_assume_aligned` is the only really portable (to GNU C compilers) way to do this**.  You can do hacks like passing pointers to `struct aligned_floats { alignas(32) float f[8]; };`, but that's just cumbersome to use, and unless you actually access memory through objects of that type, it doesn't get compilers to assume alignment.  (e.g. casting a pointer to that back to `float *`

---

> I try to use one read and lots of write to saturate the cpu ports for writing.

Using more than 4 output streams can hurt by resulting in more conflict misses in the cache.  Skylake's L2 cache is only 4-way, for example.  But L1d is 8-way so you're probably ok for small buffers.

If you want to saturate the store port uop throughput, use narrower stores (e.g. scalar), not wide SIMD stores that need more bandwidth per uop.  Back-to-back stores to the same cache line may be able to merge in the store buffer before committing to L1d, so it depends what you want to test.

Semi-related: a 2x load + 1x store memory access pattern like `c[i] = a[i]+b[i]` or STREAM triad will come closest to [maxing out total L1d cache load+store bandwidth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329789/how-can-cache-be-that-fast/329955#329955) on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs.  On SnB/IvB, 256-bit vectors take 2 cycles per load/store, leaving time for store-address uops to use the AGUs on ports 2 or 3 during the 2nd cycle of a load.  On Haswell and later (256-bit wide load/store ports), the stores need to use a non-indexed addressing mode so they can use the simple-addressing-mode store AGU on port 7.

But AMD CPUs can do up-to-2 memory ops per clock, with at most one being a store, so they'd max out with a copy-and-operate stores = loads pattern.

BTW, Intel recently announced Sunny Cove (successor to Ice Lake), which will have [2x load + 2x store throughput](https://fuse.wikichip.org/news/1941/intel-reveals-10nm-sunny-cove-core-a-new-core-roadmap-and-teases-ice-lake-chips/2/) per clock, a 2nd vector shuffle ALU, and 5-wide issue/rename.  So that's fun!  Compilers will need to unroll loops by at least 2 to not bottleneck on 1-per-clock loop branches.

---

**Footnote 1**: That's why (if you compile without AVX), you get a warning, and gcc omits an `and rsp,-32` because it assumes RSP is already aligned.  (It doesn't actually spill any YMM regs, so it should have optimized this out anyway, but gcc has had this missed-optimization bug for a while with locals or auto-vectorization-created objects with extra alignment.)

```
<source>:4:6: note: The ABI for passing parameters with 32-byte alignment has changed in GCC 4.6
```