# What is happening in this code? reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf)

Tags: c++

It seems to me that the buffer is being modified. Does it put 6 integers and then 5 floats into the buffer? It's also strange that they set size to 44 instead of 1024*sizeof(char). Perhaps the whole buffer is passed to write() but write() writes only the first 44 bytes to the client.

Could you please explain line by line? I have no experience with c++.

```
char buf[1024];
int* pInt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf);
*pInt = 5;
*(pInt+1) = 2;
*(pInt+2) = 3;  
*(pInt+3) = 4;
*(pInt+4) = 5;
*(pInt+5) = 6;

float* pFloat = reinterpret_cast<float*>(pInt+6);
*pFloat = 111;
*(pFloat+1) = 222;
*(pFloat+2) = 333;
*(pFloat+3) = 444;
*(pFloat+4) = 555;

int n;
int size = (1+2*5)*4;
n = write(buf, size);
```

Comment: correct, 6 4 byte integers, and 5 4 byte floats, starting at position 0 of buf. writes 44 bytes of buf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it put 6 integers and then 5 floats into the buffer?

Yes.

> It's also strange that they set size to `11` instead of `1024*sizeof(char)`

They don't want to write the entire buffer. Thy want to write just the `int`s and `float`s that were written to the buffer.

FWIW, that is poorly written code. It assumes that `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` are both equal to 4. A more portable method would use:

```
int size = 6*sizeof(int) + 5*sizeof(float);
```

---

**Caution**

Even though the posted code might work under some, perhaps most, circumstances,  use of

```
int* pInt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf);
*pInt = 5;
```

is cause for undefined behavior by the standard. It violates the strict aliasing rule. There wasn't an `int` to begin with at that location.

Had you used:

```
int array[5] = {};
char* cp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(array);

// ...

int* iptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(cp);
*iptr = 10;
```

there would be no problem since `cp` points to a place where an `int` was there to begin with.

For your use case, it will be better to use:

```
char buf[1024];
int intArray[] = {5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::memcpy(buff, intArray, sizeof(intArray));

float floatArray = {111, 222, 333, 444, 555};
std::memcpy(buff+sizeof(intArray), floatArray, sizeof(floatArray));

int n;
int size = sizeof(intArray) + sizeof(floatArray);
n = write(buf, size);
```

Further reading:

1. [reinterpret_cast creating a trivially default-constructible object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873520/reinterpret-cast-creating-a-trivially-default-constructible-object)
2. [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)

Comment: No, `reinterpret_cast` does not create objects. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40873520/3002139

Comment: You may want to note this [violates stict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/1708801) and the correct way to type pun in C++ is [via memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31080901/1708801)

Comment: @BaummitAugen where does the answer state that `reinterpret_cast` creates objects or assumes so?

Comment: @Fureeish *"Does it put 6 integers and then 5 floats into the buffer? Yes."* <- There. There are no integer of float objects at the relevant places in this code.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Strict aliasing doesn't apply to `char*` pointers, though.  It is an explicit exception to the rule. And a `char[]` array decays into a `char*` pointer.

Comment: @BaummitAugen so you're saying that `int* pInt = reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf); *pInt = 5;` does not correctly place the binary sequence that represents an integer `5` in the very beginning of memory occupied by `buf`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is absolutely wrong, you are allowed to alias via a `char` but this code aliases via an `int` and `float` both are very much strict aliasing violations.

Comment: @Fureeish It's not about the binary sequence either. There just is no `int` object that can be assigned to to begin with. Read the link.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not strict aliasing. `char*` may alias anything.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, sorta. If I am not mistaken, "Any pointer type -> `char*` -> same pointer type -> deference pointer" is ok. "`char*` -> another pointer type -> dereference pointer" violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @RSahu Hm, I think saying there is no `int` or `float` to assign to to begin with would be a more precise way of stating the core problem, wouldn't it?