# Can I leave dynamic memory for std::complex uninitialized after allocation?

Tags: c++, initialization, allocation, complex-numbers, stdlaunder

I have a container library that initializes elements **only if** they are **not** "is_trivially_default_constructible".
In principle, I use the `std::is_trivially_default_constructible` trait to determine this.

I think this should work if the trait reflects reality, for example `int`s and `double`s are left uninitialized in effect.

**1. Is it ok to do that, should I expect some undefined behavior?**
(Assume that elements are eventually formed by assignment.)

There are plenty examples like that where it is suggested that one uses a special allocator in which the `construct` function is a no-op.

If the answer above is positive, what can it be said about the following more complicated case:

In turn, I also use the mechanism and "overwrite" the behavior for `std::complex<double>`.
That is I treat `std::complex<double>` as if `is_trivially_default_constructible` were true.
(It is not true, because [the default constructor of std::complex is stupid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27290766/uninitialized-stdcomplex-constructor-when-using-new).)

**2. Is it ok if I don't initialize the memory for a type that technically is not trivial to default-construct? Should I "bless" somehow this memory with `std::launder` or something like that?**

Comment: Only since C++20 do we have implicit lifetime types which `std::complex` is not so the only way to create one is with an initialization (a definition / new)

Comment: On that topic: `std::complex<double>* cp = std::malloc(elems * sizeof *cp);` - tadaaa?

Comment: @TedLyngmo. That’s exactly the question. Is *cp a bonafide std::complex<double> for the compiler?

Comment: @alfC I think that it is since passing a pointer to `complex<double>`s into libraries wanting `double*`s is actually defined to work. I'm hoping for someone more language-savvy to post an actual answer though. If that doesn't happen in a day or two, I might give it a go.

Comment: std::complex is supposed to be compatible with C complex, so yeah I would say it is pretty safe.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, so do you think that the special rules that apply to `std::complex<T>` (reinterpretable as T[2]) are saving me? makes sense.

Comment: @alfC I think it does but since I find the standard hard to read so it usually takes me hours to come to any conclusion (if any) - and I haven't even started looking at it. Perhaps you should add the [language-lawyer] tag on this one? I have a feeling it will come down to a language lawyering answer in the end anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think the lawyering is what made them write some special rules for complex, see the section "Array-oriented access" in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex.

Comment: @alfC Yes, that part I find clear. It's the "object" part that you mentioned above I'm not 100% sure about. C++20's implicit lifetime types that Nathan mentioned is one thing but my gut feeling is that it was defined before that too via  piling up a bunch of paragraphs. Just a feeling right now.